# Why is the output after division a "@" symbol?

Tags: nasm

Im trying to input 3 spaced numbers in the form of: 4 2 2

divide the first two numbers and then multiply by the remaining digit. When I attempt to divide the two numbers (dig1 & dig2), I get a "@" symbol. How can I get it to print out the answer (2)?

Here is a picture of the output (notice the 4 2 2 managed to output successfully
[image: Picture]

```
section .data

msg db  'Enter three numbers to !',0xa  ;our dear string
len equ $ - msg     

section .bss 
dig1 resb 2
dig2 resb 2
dig3 resb 2
filler resb 1
res resb 1

section .text
    global _start       
_start:                   
;dig1 input
mov eax, 3
mov ebx, 0
mov ecx, dig1
mov edx, 2
int 0x80

;dig1 output
mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, dig1
mov edx, 2
int 0x80

;dig2 input
mov eax, 3
mov ebx, 0
mov ecx, dig2
mov edx, 2
int 0x80

;dig2 output
mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, dig2
mov edx, 2
int 0x80

;dig3 input
mov eax, 3
mov ebx, 0
mov ecx, dig3
mov edx, 2
int 0x80


;dig3 output
mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, dig3
mov edx, 2
int 0x80

;divide first digits
mov ax, [dig1]
sub ax, '0'
mov bx, [dig2]
sub bx, '0'
div bx
add ax, '0'
mov [res], ax
sub ax, '0'



mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, res
mov edx, 1
int 0x80

;System exit
mov eax, 1
mov ebx, 0
int 0x80
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get right answer, just before `div`, you need to:

- Filter out extra space character in `AX`,
- Filter out extra space character in `BX`, and
- Zero out `DX`

[Previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66201566/2311255) and its comments mentioned why and how to get done first two. I'll try to explain why the last is need.

According to [X86 instruction reference of `DIV`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/div), you are using `DIV r/m16` version. (Here, `r/m16` roughly means `either 16-bit register or 16-bit memory contents`, and you are using 16-bit register `BX`.) It says `Unsigned divide DX:AX by r/m16, with result stored in AX ← Quotient, DX ← Remainder`. In other words, `div` brings both `DX` and `AX`, concatenates to make one 32-bit number, and then divide by `r/m16` (= `BX` in your code).

By zeroing out `DX`, the quantity of 16-bit unsigned number `AX` remains same as that of 32-bit unsigned number `DX:AX`.

Comment: How do you filter out the extra space characters, is it the same as zeroing out DX which is essentialy mov dx, 0

Comment: @jameson :: [Please refer this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66201439/why-is-the-output-after-division-a-symbol#comment117041151_66201566) for filter out space character. And yes, zeroing out means `mov DX, 0` .

Answer (score 0):

Right before you execute `div`, this is what the registers look like:

> $eax   : 0x2004
> $ebx   : 0x2002
> $ecx   : 0x0804a020  →  0x00000a32 ("2\n"?)
> $edx   : 0x2

The leading 20 is from the space that you read in along with the digit. After the `div`, `eax` holds `0x10`, then you add `0x30` to it, making it `0x40`. `0x40` is the ASCII code for `@`.

To fix this, you could do a separate read to discard the spaces and only read in a single character at a time, or read in the space like you are, then clear out the top of the word to remove the space from the register before doing math.

---

If you aren't already using it, a debugger like GDB is crucial. Get GDB, then maybe a add-on like GEF to clean up the output a bit.

Comment: Thank you, the assignment requires the spaces. How would I clear out the top of the word? Also Ive tried compiling NASM on my MacBook but It does not work will GDB run with IOS?

Comment: I'm hesitant to give advice there because I'm still learning myself. `and ax, 0x00FF` can be used though to keep only the lower 8 bits (4 for each `F`). I don't believe that that has any drawbacks.

Comment: And I'm assuming there's a vrsion of GDB for macs. If not, there's some debugger available (there has to be).

Comment: I've now added filler inputs to clear the spaces, however, Im getting "6" as an output after dividing 4/2... now I'm even more confused